# How can I use vue.js environment variables like BASE_URL at CSS background: url(...)

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to solve the challegene like

```
<template>
 <div :style="{background: 'url($publicPath)img.gif'}"></div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  data() {
   return {
    publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily render the image using [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like:

```
<div :style="{background: `url(${publicPath}img.gif)`}"></div>
```

**Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data() {
   return {
    publicPath: 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/'
   }
  }
})
```

```css
.image { width:200px; height: 200px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp">
  <div :style="{background: `url(${publicPath}pic_trulli.jpg)`}" class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works! 
But it doesn‘t work with the environment variable. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you using vue CLI or using vuejs with Node?

Comment: I’m using Vue CLI

Comment: have you looked into [Modes and Environment Variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes)? Also, have you added BASE_URL in the `.env` file.

Comment: Yes, I use the environment variable BASE_URL at the img tag successfully - like in the documentation

Comment: <img :src="`${publicPath}my-image.png`">

Comment: You mean publicPath is working fine for an image but not for div? Can you please create a small demo for this using codesandbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215841/discussion-between-julius-and-pala).